# Core Data - copy a relationship to a new entity?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to create a new Core Data entity and copy [some of] its contents from an old entity, using the following (simplified) code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
MyEntity *newEntity = [[MyEntity alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
newEntity.myRelationship = oldEntity.myRelationship;
```

Before the last assignment is executed, `oldEntity` has an object pointed by `myRelationship`.

After the assignment, `newEntity.myRelationship` points to the same object, but `oldEntity.myRelationship` becomes `nil`.

What do I have to do to keep the object in the old entity as well as in the new entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is of type `X`.
`oldEntity` and `newEntity` both have a `one-to-one` relation ship to `X`.

I think your relationship from `X` to the old and new entity type is also `one-to-one`.
You should change this.

In your core data model you can change this.
It should look like:

`Type X <-->> Type Y`
Where type `Y` is the type for your old and new entity.

You should regenerate your `NSManagedObject` class for Type `X`. If you have logic in  the implementation, you should copy and paste it in the new generated file.

Note that entity X has now more then 1 entity of type Y, so it will be a collection instead of a single entity.

Comment: Note: if you want to keep the relationship in the first object, you maybe want to choose another word instead of `old`. It implies that the object should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the 1:1 relationship is only enforced when the entity is saved (I need the old data temporarily before it's saved). As for the names, this is a simplified code, not my actual code - but eventually the old entity IS being removed so using OLD could be appropriate.